# Google Data Studio - group requests

Tags: looker-studio

### Summary

We are using our custom Google Data Studio connector. 
We've faced an issue for reports based on it: there are as many requests as widgets on a page, even if filters are same.

### Question

Is there any possibility to send one request for all widgets on page (if filters are the same)?

Approach with grouped widgets were already used, it didn't help.
There were 6 widgets + daterange selector and 6 API requests were received.

### Additional info

**Expected result:** while having several widgets with same filter - only **1 request per page** is sent to API.

**Actual result:** there is **1 request per each widget** on a page.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This is the expected behavior. Data Studio can't guarantee that batching requests to an end point will result in the same data as separate requests due to aggregations & non-tabular schemas.

Many endpoints can't support all of their schema fields being requested at the same time.